# TYPO3 - HTML RTE frontend rendering is not working

Tags: typo3, typoscript, html-rendering

I have the latest version of TYPO3, and the data I entered in the RTE is not rendered properly in the frond end (in site).

So for example `<p>asdf</p>` will show as it is in frond end.

I googled it and tried with some RTE default configuration changes, but that did not work well.

Comment: Can you post some more information? For instance how the output looks like and which configuration you used.

Comment: I think that he has some kind of `htmlspecialchars` rule inside his TS or he has some kind of strange RTE config in backend.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with some basic testing first.

1. Create a new site on root level (directly below the globe). Create one content element with all text and styles you want to test.
2. Create a new Typoscript template for this site and put the following in the setup section:

   page = PAGE
   page.10 < styles.content.get

Make sure to include `CSS Styled content` inside the static template section.

Now watch your page page in frontend. Does it work?

Otherwise try step 0. and create a new (admin) backend user first.

Most likely you have either a strange transformation rule inside your RTE config in backend (`UserTS` or `PageTS`) or you have some kind of `htmlspecialchar` definition for your frontend rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Please post something of the following basic Typo3 configuration settings and/or tell us if you use something of that:

You Upgraded from an older Typo3 version? Than it could be, that some configuration is missing.

Root Template or Site Template inside Typo3 Backend you can create or edit one, when you click in the most left menu on "Template"

If you choose "Create Template for new site" button the most basic Typo3 Typoscript * is automatically created

```
# Default PAGE object:
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value = HELLO WORLD!
```

Do you have such an TS (= Typoscript) tested? **TEST IT and tell us if it works!!!**
Does this work for you?

- (Typo3's own configuration language - both a blessing and a curse - can be so easy and so painful - most laughful description i ever read, you can found on  hatetypo3.blogspot.de "spaghetti code festival")

Don't miss include "CSS styled content" (it's in the form "edit whole template -> Includes)
But if you don't have include this, normally no site content is displayed in the frontend.

Another way is to include basic TS configuration in one or mor separate files. To get the files working, you have to referce them by this snippet in a Site Template in the BE

```
   <INCLUDE_TYPOSCRIPT: source="FILE: yourfile">   
   # BTW I saw that it is common to place the file in a dir like 
   /fileadmin/ts/yourtyposcriptfile.ts
```

So give us this info or ask for more, if i miss something.